# Check if fragment is visible from service

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a GCMListenerService (Google Cloud Messaging) for a messaging app. When i recieve a message onMessageRecieved() I need to be able to check if a specific fragment is visible to the user. If it is then i can send a broadcast to that fragment to update the UI otherwise i need to create a notification. Any ideas how i could do this. I am aware that the fragment (and even the activity) may not be open which is precisely why i must check before trying to send a broadcast, any ideas? Can i pass the activity content to the service so i can call getFragmentManager() ?

Answer (score 2):

I think the reliable way would be to notify service from within the fragment of its visibility, for example using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) or IBinder implementation (EventBus won't work if the service runs in different process than the fragment). Just send a message to service when the fragment is resumed and send another when it's paused, and accordingly set some flag in service that will indicate whether it should post a notification or send a broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this will suitable with your question because i did not see your code but you can check your fragment is visible to user or not with this method

```
@Override
     public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
     if (isVisibleToUser) {
      // TODO

     }
```